# Biztalk - convert from ANSI to UTF-8

Tags: biztalk, ansi, edi, x12

How can I convert a x12 EDI file from ANSI to UTF-8 in a receive pipeline? So Before it's been dissasembled.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  The EDI Disassembler supports ANSI just fine.  Also, keep in mind that ANSI to UTF-8 should be indistinguishable.  The lower char range is identical.

Comment: The ANSI file I received contained some weird characters. I could change the edi receive pipeline to UTF-8 but it didn't receive it as UTF-8 (setting seems doesn't seem to be applied). I created a custom receive pipeline with the setting of the disassembler to UTF-8 in VS. Then it worked.

Comment: Well, what do you mean weird characters?  That's suggests it not ANSI but UTF-8 without the BOM.